# List of known bugs in C# compiler

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Is there such a list? I don't expect to get a complete one, but the list of most well-known ones must be enough.

Comment: If some bug is 'buggin' you, try gmcs.exe, which comes with the Mono framework.

Comment: @Dykam - what, and that is bug free? I've reported multiple compiler bugs in gmcs. They are just as prone to error.

Comment: Surely not bugfree, but if a csc bug bugs you, you can try it with gmcs.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Because we use it. I know it's quite stable, on the other hand, I was sure there are some issues, and I remember we've been facing some of them. I was pretty sure if there is such a list, there must be rather tricky cases related to C# syntax. So the question is more educational then really practical.

Comment: Btw, I'm one of readers of russian version of your blog, Eric ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the list of recently fixed bugs could be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713578.aspx
They call it "Breaking changes".

Comment: Like so many of M$ documentation links, this one is broken, too.

Answer (score 5):

Try http://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/default.aspx?SiteID=210

Which version of the .Net framework btw?

I believe that the CLR has been largely stable and bug free since .Net 1.1 SP 1, certainly if in doubt, assume that its a bug in your code not .Net!

Comment: The compiler has some real bugs, one related to enums. That bug is going to be a feature btw.

Comment: We're using .NET 3.5 SP1 now.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler emits calls to the constructor System.Decimal(int32, int32, int32, bool, byte) for decimal literals like the following:

```
public static readonly decimal MaxValue = 79228162514264337593543950335M;
```

If you are implementing mscorlib, and you leave out this constructor, the C# compiler *crashes* rather than giving [error message CS0656](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ed82w55.aspx) indicating a member required by the compiler is missing.

I know of bugs in the C# IntelliSense engine, the .NET debugger, and in the .NET framework, but you just asked about the compiler. :o